# Does the content of UniformBuffer need to be sent to GPU in each frame

Tags: c++, vulkan

If you want to see the whole code, [here](https://github.com/VisualGMQ/toy2d/tree/da748027c98cd94a484e5ccfa3dcc9c9870aecb2).

I'm following the [vulkan tutorial](https://vulkan-tutorial.com/Uniform_buffers), in the chapter "Uniform Buffers",it use only one uniform buffer to let shader use MVP matrixes.Now I want to add a extra uniform buffer to change the triangle's color, the codes are:

vertex shader code(use MVP):

```c
#version 450

layout(location = 0) in vec2 inPosition;

layout(binding = 0) uniform UniformBuffer {
    mat4 project;
    mat4 view;
    mat4 model;
} ubo;

void main() {
    gl_Position = ubo.project * ubo.view * ubo.model * vec4(inPosition, 0.0, 1.0);
}
```

fragment shader code(use color):

```c
#version 450

layout(location = 0) out vec4 outColor;

layout(binding = 1) uniform UniformBuffer {
    vec3 color;
} ubo;

void main() {
    outColor = vec4(ubo.color, 1.0);
}
```

In order todo that, I use two `DescriptorSetLayoutBinding` to bind to 0 and 1, and two uniform buffer to store MVP and color separately.I also update `DescriptorSet` with these buffers:

```cpp
void Renderer::updateDescriptorSets() {
    for (int i = 0; i < descriptorSets_.size(); i++) {
        // bind MVP buffer
        vk::DescriptorBufferInfo bufferInfo1;
        bufferInfo1.setBuffer(deviceUniformBuffers_[i]->buffer)
                   .setOffset(0)
           .setRange(sizeof(float) * 4 * 4 * 3);

        std::vector<vk::WriteDescriptorSet> writeInfos(2);
        writeInfos[0].setBufferInfo(bufferInfo1)
                     .setDstBinding(0)
                     .setDescriptorType(vk::DescriptorType::eUniformBuffer)
                     .setDescriptorCount(1)
                     .setDstArrayElement(0)
                     .setDstSet(descriptorSets_[i]);

        // bind Color buffer
        vk::DescriptorBufferInfo bufferInfo2;
        bufferInfo2.setBuffer(deviceColorBuffers_[i]->buffer)
                   .setOffset(0)
                   .setRange(sizeof(float) * 3);

        writeInfos[1].setBufferInfo(bufferInfo2)
                     .setDstBinding(1)
                     .setDstArrayElement(0)
                     .setDescriptorCount(1)
                     .setDescriptorType(vk::DescriptorType::eUniformBuffer)
                     .setDstSet(descriptorSets_[i]);

        Context::Instance().device.updateDescriptorSets(writeInfos, {});
    }
}
```

And I try to imitate SDL: set once renderer's color at beginning and draw rect each frame:

```cpp
    // in main.cpp
    toy2d::Color color{0, 1, 0};
    renderer->SetDrawColor(color);
    while (!shouldClose) {
        while (SDL_PollEvent(&event)) {
            // some event handle operations
        }
        renderer->DrawRect(toy2d::Rect{toy2d::Vec{100, 100},
                                       toy2d::Size{200, 300}});
    }
```

the `renderer->SetDrawColor(color)` only transform the color data to GPU:

```cpp
void Renderer::SetDrawColor(const Color& color) {
    auto& uniformBuffer = colorBuffers_[curFrame_];
    auto& device = Context::Instance().device;
    void* ptr = device.mapMemory(uniformBuffer->memory, 0, uniformBuffer->requireSize);
        memcpy(ptr, (void*)&color, sizeof(float) * 3);
    device.unmapMemory(uniformBuffer->memory);

    transformBuffer2Device(*uniformBuffer, *deviceColorBuffers_[curFrame_],
                           0, // Src Offset
                           0, // Des Offset,
                           sizeof(float) * 3 // Size
                          );
}
```

But it can't work! The triangle flicker between green and black. I tried to use RenderDoc to grab one frame and find that no data in color uniform buffer.
I tried to move `renderer->SetDrawColor(color)` into the render loop, and it performs OK.So does vulkan make uniform buffer invalid after drawing command executed? Or some other reson? Please tell me and I will appreciate you.

Comment: First, never unmap memory. Second, you're modifying memory the GPU is using. So where is your synchronization?

Comment: @NicolBolas  Thank you.I do not synchronize the buffer because the tutorial don't do that so. And I will follow your advise, thanks again.